# Python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, command, bots

Im trying to make a bot that can create roles but the bot is not recognizing my command.

I have tried using [OpenAI](https://chat.openai.com/chat) but its knowledge is limited. I just need a working way to receive commands and create the roles. This is one of the biggest

```
import sys

command_prefix = "!"

async def create_role(guild, role_name):
  # Create the role
  role = await guild.create_role(name=role_name)
  return role

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith(f"{command_prefix}gr"):
    # Split the message into a list of arguments
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    # The name of the role is the second argument
    role_name = args[1]
    print(f"Creating role {role_name}")  # Debug statement
    # Create the role
    role = await create_role(message.guild, role_name)
    # Give the role to the user who sent the message
    await assign_role(message.author, role)
    await message.channel.send(
      f'Created role {role_name} and gave it to {message.author}')
client.run(
  'TOKEN')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "_This is one of the biggest_" one of the biggest what?

Answer (score 0):

You should use commands

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!') # prefix

@bot.command(name = "gr") # gr would be an example command, !gr <something>
async def do_on_command_function(ctx, msg):
    # msg will store the message after the command
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: Can you explain how I would use that to send a message in a channel? I'm not sure where to implement @bot.command(name = "gr"). I tried replacing @client.event with that but it gave me errors saying `undefined name 'bot'`

Comment: The `undefined name 'bot'` error is probably because you're forgetting to declare the variable. For sending a message you should use the `ctx` variable, you can use that variable for interacting with all discord-related things, like roles.
Remember that all these commands staff is in order to send a response given a command, for sending a message without any command, you can send a POST request to `https://discord.com/api/channels/{chat_id}/messages`, you can see more in [discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro).